# An error occurs when using Taglist plugin in vim

Tags: vim

I am new to vim , I installed a plugin named Taglist from [here](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/)

When I restart my vim, a error happens:

> Taglist: Exuberant ctags (http://ctags.sf.net) not found in PATH. Plugin is not loaded.

How to solve this?

Comment: Accept the right answer. Installing ctags works.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am guessing you did not install ctags. The installation instructions skip that.
If you are on ubuntu or similar debian based OS do:

```
sudo apt-get install ctags
```

Answer (score 4):

What about installing Exuberant ctags to your `path`? Maybe you should read the [installation instructions](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/installation.html) for your brand new plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I installed amix/vimrc on my new fedora 19 installation and encountered with same error regarding ctags.

I ran this command to resolve my error on fedora 19 - Red Hat Based Distribution

```
yum install ctags
```